# How do i group by year instead of months?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file which has a period column that records the arrival counts in months. However, i would like to calculate the arrival counts in terms of year.

This is how the csv file looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpERT.png

I have already sorted out the region by cor and moa, so now i need to sort them by year.

Here is my code:

```
data2 = df[df['region'] == 'ASIA'].groupby(['cor','moa']).sum()
```

Comment: put data as text (not image) so we could run it, see problem, and create code with solution.

Comment: Do `print(data2)` and copy & paste that in your question instead of an image. We cannot copy your image.

Comment: The image that i have provided is a csv file which i cant sent

Comment: The image is an excel file, not a csv. A [csv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) is a simple text file. After you read it in pandas, it's enough if you print `df` and copy-paste few lines in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that after you read the CSV file, you changed *period* column to
*Period* type, calling e.g.:

```
df.period = df.period.apply(pd.Period)
```

If you want to group (and sum) *avr_count* values **only** by year,
then there is no need to call *groupby* explicitely.
Instead you could write e.g.:

```
df[df.region == 'ASIA'].set_index('period')['avr_count'].resample('Y').sum()
```

But if you want the year as an **additional** grouping level, then write:

```
df[df.region == 'ASIA'].set_index('period')\
    .groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='Y'), 'cor', 'moa']).sum()
```

In the above example the year is the **first** grouping level, but you
can put it also e.g. as the **last** level.